# sorting not working with the channel

Tags: sorting

I am facing the problem for the sorting on the channel by passing the value on orderby dynamically (with the custom fields & for date sort)

Always resulting out me same data

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="careers" orderby=""}
```

Please advise ASAP

Comment: 1. We can't answer you ASAP. We're volunteers, not an official support channel.

2. Have you set the [dynamic parameters](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic-parameters)?

Comment: Please provide more details of how you're passing the value "dynamically" - give more of your template example. Are you using PHP? How do you know that the result is as you've displayed?